# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.addDeprecation

Tags: hadoop

I plan to install `hive0.12` with `hadoop-1.2.1`. After `hadoop-1.2.1` installed,I also have configured `hive0.12`. But when I use `bin/hive` command I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.addDeprecation(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf.<clinit>(HiveConf.java:77)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.common.LogUtils.initHiveLog4jCommon(LogUtils.java:74)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.common.LogUtils.initHiveLog4j(LogUtils.java:58)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:639)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:623)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:160)
```

how to solve the problem?

Comment: It seems you are using incompatible/different version of hadoop common jar file. Use the jar file which contains this method in the Configuration class.

Answer (score 5):

### Reason

**org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.addDeprecation()** method is added from hadoop 2.3.0. But as you wrote, your hadoop distribution is 1.2.1. In short, your hive installation and hadoop installation are not fit each other. Your hive installation must be rebuilded for hadoop 1.2.1.

### Solution

#### First choice: upgrade your hadoop installation to 2.x.x

This approach is the easist one. As hadoop 1.2.1 will not be updated anymore, upgrading your installation is feasible. Remove your current hadoop installation and install hadoop 2.5.1(the latest version, as of now.). For installing it, his [tutorial](http://raseshmori.wordpress.com/2012/10/14/install-hadoop-nextgen-yarn-multi-node-cluster/) is recommended.

#### Second choice: rebuild your hive distribution for hadoop 1.2.1

You must builded your hive distribution with following command, when you installed it:

```
mvn clean install -Phadoop-2,dist
```

Try this command:

```
mvn clean install -Phadoop-1,dist
```

With this command, the output will be created in **packaging/target/apache-hive-0.12-bin** directory. Replace your current hive installtion with it.

Answer (score 3):

remove your hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar dependency,it works for me

Answer (score 1):

You might have placed `hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar` in `Hadoop 2.x.x` class-path directory, remove it. (It worked for me)